# Ограничение на количество новых записей в базу данных

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте, есть форма регистрации на семинар, данные инпутов добавляются в бд. Нужно ограничить количество зарегистрированных участников 50-ю, и чтобы, например, при регистрации 51-го появлялся alert или echo о том что необходимое количество участников уже набрано или при >50 записей в бд, ссылка на регистрацию\кнопка отправки формы скрывалась\становилась неактивной.
Возможно ли организовать нечто подобное?

Всем огромное спасибо, получилось организовать через echo:

//reg.html

```
<form method="post" action="reg.php">
<strong>Ф.И.О.:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="userName" size="50"/><br />
<strong>ID:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="id" size="50"/>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение"/></p>
</form>
```

//reg.php

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
mysql_query('set character_set_client="utf8"');
mysql_query('set character_set_results="utf8"');
$max = 50;
$value = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) from test;");
$actual = mysql_result($value, 0);
if ($actual > $max) {
    echo "<b>К сожалению, свободные все свободные места на семинаре закончились</b><br>";
    echo "<a href=/>Вернуться на страницу мероприятия</a>";
exit;
}
else {

$userName = $_REQUEST['userName'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
if (empty($userName))
{
    echo "<b>Пожалуйста, заполните поле Ф.И.О.</b><br>";
    echo "<a href=reg.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
exit;
} 
if (empty($id))
{
    echo "<b>Пожалуйста, заполните поле id</b><br>";
    echo "<a href=reg.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
exit;
} 
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO test (id, userName)" .
"VALUES('{$id}', '{$userName}');";
mysql_query($insert_sql);
    echo "<b>Вы успешно зарегестрированы!</b><br>";
    echo "<a href=/>Вернуться на страницу мероприятия</a>";
exit;
}
?>
```

Теперь ищу как с помощью js прикрутить к кнопке проверку описанного в php с выводом alert (вместо echo) чтобы все сообщения всплывали на одной странице.

Comment: перед формированием формы регистрации сформировать запрос на кол-во уже зареганых, если > 50, алерт вывести, форму формировать неактивной

Comment: если совсем запретить в таблице быть больше чем 50 записям `alter thetable MAX_ROWS=50`и обрабатывайте ошибки при insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что в данном случае лучше выполнять проверку в приложении, чем ограничивать количество строк в базе (учитывая идеи по типу *ссылка на регистрацию\кнопка отправки формы скрывалась\становилась неактивной*).

На странице с формой выполните запрос к базе для получения к-ва записей:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM your_table;
```

В скрипте, на странице сделайте проверку, вроде следующей:

```
$max = 50;
if ($count >= $max) {
    $soldout = true;
}
```

Теперь отрисовывайте шаблон, исходя из значения переменной `$soldout`, скрывайте кнопку оформления заявки, выводите алерт.
Также, можете добавить колонку active в Вашу таблицу, чтобы можно было таким образом отсеивать не подтвердившиеся заявки на участие (в подобных задачах это бывает необходимо). Тогда запрос на получение колличества активных заявок будеи выглядеть так:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM your_table WHERE active=1;
```

Аналогично можно добавить другие фильтры.